# Keeping Special Characters in Spark Table Column Name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hiveql

Is there any way to keep special characters for a column in a spark 3.0 table?

I need to do something like

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table
AS
SELECT id=abc
FROM tbl1
```

I was reading in Hadoop that you would put back ticks around the column name but this does not work in spark.

If there is a way to do this in PySpark that would work as well

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you parquet and delta formats do not accept special characters under any circumstance. You must use Row Format Delimited

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE schema.test
             ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
             SELECT 1 AS `brand=one` """)
```